# Wagtail: How to use wagtailuserbar for moderation (approving and rejecting draft posts)

Tags: wagtail

We are using the wagtailuserbar templatetag on our site and it works fine for published pages. We get the "Edit this page" and "View in admin" options etc.

The documentation says that wagtailuserbar can also be used by moderators to approve/reject drafts but I can't get this work.

Quote from the [documentation](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.8.1/topics/writing_templates.html#wagtail-user-bar):

> Moderators are also given the ability to accept or reject a page being previewed as part of content moderation.

This screenshot shows the admin website with a page that has been submitted for moderation:

[image: pages submitted for moderation]

Clicking the preview link opens a new tab but the wagtail userbar is not visible.

If one instead uses the View Draft feature in the page explorer then again, new tab but no userbar.

[image: page explorer]

Looking at the [source code here](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/stable/2.8.x/wagtail/admin/templatetags/wagtailuserbar.py) these lines seem to remove the userbar for any preview view:

```
# Don't render if this is a preview. Since some routes can render the userbar without going through Page.serve(),
# request.is_preview might not be defined.
if getattr(request, 'is_preview', False):
    return ''
```

My question is:
How can I use the wagtail userbar to approve or reject previews of pages submitted for moderation? The documentation suggests this is possible but experience and my understanding of the code suggests not.

It's a feature I'd really love to use.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for this very clear description of the problem. I think this is a bug, which I've raised here:

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/6008